# perl remove trailing line not working

Tags: perl, chomp, chop

This is workfile.txt

```
 NC_001778

NC_005252

NC_004744

NC_003096

NC_005803
```

I want to read it in array and have only the string without spaces or lines . 
this code does what I want on my laptop but it's not working on the linux desktop!

```
  @nodes=<nodefile>;
  chomp @nodes; 

foreach my $el(@nodes){
        chop ($el);
   }
print Dumper @nodes;
#output: `bash-4.2$ perl main.pl
';AR1 = 'NC_000893
';AR2 = 'NC_001778
';AR3 = 'NC_005252
';AR4 = 'NC_004744
';AR5 = 'NC_003096
';AR6 = 'NC_005803
```

`

```
    #hexdump -C workfile.txt |head -20

00000000  4e 43 5f 30 30 30 38 39  33 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_000893...NC_0|
00000010  30 31 37 37 38 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 30 35 32 35  |01778...NC_00525|
00000020  32 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  30 34 37 34 34 0d 0d 0a  |2...NC_004744...|
00000030  4e 43 5f 30 30 33 30 39  36 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_003096...NC_0|
00000040  30 35 38 30 33 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 30 36 35 33  |05803...NC_00653|
00000050  31 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  30 34 34 31 37 0d 0d 0a  |1...NC_004417...|
00000060  4e 43 5f 30 31 33 36 33  33 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_013633...NC_0|
00000070  31 33 36 31 38 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 30 32 37 36  |13618...NC_00276|
00000080  31 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  31 33 36 32 38 0d 0d 0a  |1...NC_013628...|
00000090  4e 43 5f 30 30 35 32 39  39 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_005299...NC_0|
000000a0  31 33 36 30 39 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 31 33 36 31  |13609...NC_01361|
000000b0  32 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  30 32 36 34 36 0d 0d 0a  |2...NC_002646...|
000000c0  4e 43 5f 30 30 34 35 39  35 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_004595...NC_0|
000000d0  30 32 37 33 34 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 30 34 35 39  |02734...NC_00459|
000000e0  38 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  30 34 35 39 34 0d 0d 0a  |8...NC_004594...|
000000f0  4e 43 5f 30 30 38 34 34  38 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_008448...NC_0|
00000100  30 34 35 39 33 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 30 32 36 34  |04593...NC_00264|
00000110  37 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  30 32 36 37 34 0d 0d 0a  |7...NC_002674...|
00000120  4e 43 5f 30 30 33 31 36  33 0d 0d 0a 4e 43 5f 30  |NC_003163...NC_0|
00000130  30 33 31 36 34 0d 0d 0a  4e 43 5f 30 32 30 31 35  |03164...NC_02015|
```

any suggestion ? thanks in advance

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: 'NC_000893'without spaces or endline

Comment: Is there a stackoverflow question which has a good, recommended solution for this rather common dos-line-endings problem?

Comment: @TLP this is very uncommon one => `\r\r\n`

Comment: @mpapec Yes, I saw that. So rephrase to "the" rather common dos-line-endings problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have Windows line endings in this file, which is why when you use linux, your `chomp` is not removing line endings properly. It does not explain why `chop` does not remove the last character, which should be `\r` after `chomp`.

Your output

```
';AR6 = 'NC_005803
```

Indicates that the last character in the string is in fact `\r`. This is not an actual problem with the string, just with the visual representation. If you want to see this character written out literally, you can use the option

```
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
```

Which will then produce the output

```
$VAR6 = "NC_005803\r";
```

**How to fix it?**

A simple fix is to use the `dos2unix` utility in linux to fix the file. To fix it in Perl, you can do something like

```
s/[\r\n]*\z// for @nodes;  # remove all \r and \n  from end of string
s/\s*\z// for @nodes;      # remove all whitespace from end of string
s/\r//g   for @nodes;      # remove all \r from string
tr/\r//d  for @nodes;      # same
```